# Go: How to create a http proxy pass without loading body

Tags: go, http, curl

I have N agents around the world. I need to call some endpoints through these agents but without loading their bodies.
For example I want to call google.com and I send this url to all N agents and they send an http request with method GET to google.com send the response to me.
Problem is all agents are loading the full body response but I only need the response status and headers. Is there any solution in Golang to prevent downloading body response in the first place?

I tried calling it with some curl flags but it is just ignoring to show the response body and in the background body is downloaded

Comment: If you call `GET` the server is required to send the body. If you only want the headers, that is what the `HEAD` method is for.

Comment: I mean, if you write your own http code you can simply close the connection after you've read the headers.

Comment: Note that there's no guarantee that the `HEAD` method will return the same status/headers as the `GET` method. E.g. [this example](https://gist.github.com/larsks/af276e5a6ab480e0262ebe06f3415cfe) would return a different `Content-type` header for `HEAD` vs `GET`.

Comment: @larsks, while the server is not guaranteed to follows any standards at all, the spec does state: `The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request`, so you can be pretty sure that you will get the same result. Yes you can close the connection, but that of course means you can't reuse what would have otherwise been a usable connection for subsequent requests.

Comment: using method HEAD is not the right solution here because we are not sure HEAD is allowed or implemented in the server. Also we need the solution for all methods, I mean we may need to call PUT and ignore the request body

Comment: Yes, if HEAD is not allowed there is no other way in HTTP to only request the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is incompatible with the HTTP protocol.

HEAD vs GET aside, let's look at this from a language/implementation independent angle.

Your HTTP client, regardless of implementation, is sending a HTTP/1.1 request to a server using the GET/POST/PUT method. What happens next is that the server receives this request, with the following payload (this assumes GET, but it's the same for all):

```
GET /somepath HTTP/1.1
Host: somedomain.com
<more request headers here>
```

At that point, the server will reply with the HTTP response headers **and** the HTTP response body. There is no way to prevent this from happening as it would literally break the HTTP protocol. You can always avoid reading the response body on the client side, but the response body will always travel "through the wire".

However, for POST/PUT (methods which require a request body to be sent), you could use the `Expect` header.

If you include the `Expect: 100-continue` header in your request, then the server will send back to you a `HTTP 100 Continue` response, which signals the client that it is clear to send the request body, at which point you can cut the connection.

This, however, means that you would not get the *actual* HTTP response code that would be sent if you had sent the request body. For example, you wouldn't get a HTTP 400 Bad Request if your payload was invalid because you actually didn't send a payload. If you sent the payload, then the server would send back a full response, *including* the body.

Unfortunately, what you are trying to achieve isn't possible.